# Oracle SQL - Query between two timestamps which span multiple days but only for certain hours during the day

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically trying to create a select query with a condition on a time span that needs to span x number of days but only between certain hours during each day (let's say 1m to 3am).

Here is what I have done, but is there a cleaner recursive way to do it ?

Thank you in advance guys !

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, ea.EMPID, COUNT(1)
FROM EMPLOYEEACTIVITY ea, EMPLOYEE e
WHERE ea.EMPID = e.ID
      AND (ea.ENTRYTIME BETWEEN '2019-02-08 01:00:00' and '2019-02-08 03:00:00' 
           OR ea.ENTRYTIME between '2019-02-07 01:00:00' and '2019-02-07 03:00:00'
           OR ea.ENTRYTIME between '2019-02-06 01:00:00' and '2019-02-06 03:00:00'
           OR ea.ENTRYTIME between '2019-02-05 01:00:00' and '2019-02-05 03:00:00'
           OR ea.ENTRYTIME between '2019-02-04 01:00:00' and '2019-02-04 03:00:00'
           OR ea.ENTRYTIME between '2019-02-03 01:00:00' and '2019-02-03 03:00:00'
           OR ea.ENTRYTIME between '2019-02-02 01:00:00' and '2019-02-02 03:00:00'
           OR ea.ENTRYTIME between '2019-02-01 01:00:00' and '2019-02-01 03:00:00')
      AND ea.status = 'CON'
GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, ea.EMPID
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC;
```

Comment: What is the reason to provide time stamp in your condition, since you are not aggregating on time as well as you are not using in your select. You can directly provide the date instead of time stamp.

Comment: Your answer below is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know how to do it. The reason why I needed to get the interval by hours is because we have a glitch and some activity happen after midnight and I wanted to extract the list of employees for whom this happens... found a great lead ;)

Comment: As a potential side-issue, remember that `between` is inclusive, so you will include rows that are exactly at 03:00:00; for time periods you generally only want up to, but not including, the upper bound (so the same exact time isn't included in consecutive periods - e.g. both 1am to 3am and 3am to 5am).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead you can do:

```
SELECT e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, ea.EMPID, COUNT(1)
FROM EMPLOYEEACTIVITY ea, EMPLOYEE e
WHERE ea.EMPID = e.ID
    AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ea.ENTRYTIME) BETWEEN 1 and 3
    AND ea.ENTRYTIME BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-02-08'
    AND ea.status = 'CON'
GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEENUMBER, ea.EMPID
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC;
```

Comment: Perfect answer. This did exactly what I needed. Thank you so much !

Comment: @SMelikian, please consider accepting the answer if this was useful to you. Thank you!

Comment: Almost perfect :-)  **(1)** You should not use string constants for dates, but date constants (i.e. precede the strings with the keyword `DATE`). **(2)** You should not use `BETWEEN` on datetimes. So this could be `AND ea.entrytime >= DATE '2019-02-01' AND ea.entrytime <  '2019-02-09'` for instance. **(3)** Don't count an expression - even when it's constant - when you merely want to count rows. SQL for counting rows is `COUNT(*)`. `COUNT(1)` instead means literally: "only count rows for which a 1 would not be null" (the optimizer seeing your mistake will convert this to `COUNT(*)` of course).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - you missed a `DATE` keyword in (2)  *8-)

Comment: @Alex Poole. Thank you for spotting this. So the example becomes `AND ea.entrytime >= DATE '2019-02-01' AND ea.entrytime < DATE '2019-02-09'`.